# Core Foundation objects and retain/release messages

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, core-foundation

Let's say we have some Core Foundation objects, such as `CGColorRef`, that are added to an `NSArray` like this:

```
CGColorRef color = ...;
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)color];
```

Since arrays retain their contents, `color` receives a `retain` message (not `CFRetain()`, right?). What happens in this case from memory management point of view?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[From Core Foundation Design Concepts](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html):

> Note from the example that the memory management functions and methods are also interchangeable—you can use `CFRelease` with a Cocoa object and `release` and `autorelease` with a Core Foundation object.

It doesn't specifically mention `retain`, but, in practice, that works as well, as do `copy` (various classes' `CFFooCreateCopy`) and `description` (`CFCopyDescription`). The last is how you can pass CF objects as the value for a `%@` formatting specification when using `NSLog` and other string-formatting functions and methods.

The result is the same: `retain` does the same as `CFRetain`, `release` does the same as `CFRelease`, etc.

A few things to be aware of:

- Prior to iOS 7 and OS X 10.9, there is no CF counterpart function to NSObject's `autorelease` method. (7 and 10.9 brought the `CFAutorelease` function.) If you're not using ARC, then, as mentioned in the documentation quoted above, you can send `autorelease` to a CF object, and it works the same as on an NSObject.
- You can send a message to `nil`, but you can't call CF functions on `NULL` (you'll crash). Quartz has some class-specific functions, such as `CGContextRetain`/`Release`, that include a `NULL` check; whether you want to use those or always do your own `NULL` checks is a matter of style.
- CF's retain and release functions work under garbage collection, whereas `retain` and `release` messages are no-ops (as if sent to `nil`). Doesn't matter unless you're working on a GC'd Mac app, in which case you will need to use `CFRetain` and `CFRelease` on CF objects.
- Similarly, under ARC, `retain` and `release` messages will be illegal and CF objects won't be automatically reference-counted. You will need to use `CFRetain` and `CFRelease` on CF objects.
- Collections always do the right thing, as documented. Usually, this means a strong reference. Outside of GC, that means the collection (array, dictionary, etc.) will retain and release its objects, whether automatically (by assignments, if its code is ARCified) or manually (by explicit `retain` and `release` messages).