# Correct Way to Cast NSArray Value into Pointer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray

What is the correct syntax to cast an `NSArray` value into a reference i.e.:

```
&([_colors objectAtIndex:0])
```

Where the object I'm retrieving is a `CGColorRef`. Trying to send the above as a parameter to a method without storing the value into a separate value. The parameter is a (CGColorRef *).

Comment: How are you putting CGColorRef values in an NSArray? They are not based on NSObject so you must be wrapping them. This means you can't get it out like you want. Why don't you want a separate variable? That will make it so much easier to use, read, and debug.

Comment: @rmaddy Actually it is possible. E.g. read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589384/core-foundation-objects-and-retain-release-messages

Comment: @Max - Cool. I learned something new. Thanks.

Comment: @maddy CoreFoundation objects are compatible with Objective-C objects. Yes, it's some of an ugly hack, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

CGColorRef is actually a pointer by itself, so you can just send it as parameter as is.

Comment: Suppose it wasn't a colorRef, how would I accomplish that do you know?

Comment: In this case with CGColorRef, using a pointer is the only way I've been able to get what I want to work, to work. I'm not sure why...I've tried it just plain like you say cause it is a pointer, but then when I change the value in the array it doesn't change the property I'm sending the pointer to.

Comment: Maybe you should use UIColor instead of CGColor

Comment: When the value in the array changes, the only way I've been getting the other value to change (the one I'm sending to via parameter) is if I declare that property as CGColorRef* , then send it &color

Comment: Yeah probably...I'd have to change too much code at this point though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what the method/function you call does is returning a `CGColorRef` object "by reference". Since the return value of `[NSArray objectAtIndex:]` is only an `expression` but not a variable, you can't take its address. Whay you can do is

```
CGColorRef color;
CallTheFunctionToObtainThe(&color);
[_colors replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:color]
```

Of course for this to be possible, `_colors` must be an instance of `NSMutableArray`.